# Image as plane alpha working in viewport render preview but not final export

Tags: transparency

I've added an image as plane for the palm tree branches.

[image]

They look great in the render preview, but in my final export they have a black border where the plane is.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Here is the blender file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10Y61n86dOw6piPl5xSJxvpuA4dyAR0OH?usp=share_link

Comment: it looks like you have overlapping faces, have you tried to avoid that?

Comment: That was it! The branches were set up as a particle system and children was set to 3 in the viewport and 100 in the render. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your particles are overlapping, avoid that